# Recreate folder hierarchy (ParentID) using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, loops, hierarchy

The target is to get folders from one system and migrate to another using API.
From system 1 I've got consistent response about folder name, it's id and parent id.

```
[{'depth': 0,
  'description': None,
  'display_order': 55,
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'Library',
  'parent_id': None,
  'suite_id': 8},
 {'depth': 1,
  'description': None,
  'display_order': 57,
  'id': 529466,
  'name': 'MYK [RE]',
  'parent_id': 1,
  'suite_id': 8},
 {'depth': 2,
  'description': None,
  'display_order': 59,
  'id': 530931,
  'name': 'MY BO',
  'parent_id': 529466,
  'suite_id': 8},
 {'depth': 3,
  'description': None,
  'display_order': 60,
  'id': 533682,
  'name': 'NU Robs',
  'parent_id': 530931,
  'suite_id': 8},
```

To create a folder in system 2 I can only send the ParentID and name.
Could you please advise the logic how to create such loop in Python.

We could send inside the loop a get request to system 2 to check the existed folders, we'll receive a name and id(but it would be id for system 2 not for the first one) and parent id(the same way).

```
folders = client.send_get('get_sections/1')

for i in folders:

    response = requests.request(
        "GET",
        url_f,
        headers=headers,
    )

    zp_folders = response.json()
    # here we could check existed folders by name
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is importand that the input is sorted by `depth`. Then you can simply iterarte through your data and be sure that the parent must have already been created in some step before. In each iteartion steo you can update a map from old id to new id. In this way you can translate between the two systems.

Pseudo code:

1. Make sure that your source data is sorted by `depth`-property.
2. Create an empty `dict`, e.g. named `id_map`, that maps ids from system 1 to system 2.
3. Loop through your data and for each node from system 1:

   - get the new id of `parent_id` from `id_map` (if it's not `None`)
   - if `parent_id` is not in `id_map` stop with an error
   - create a new node in system 2:
   - store the mapping of old id to new id in `id_map`

Comment: We could send inside the loop a get request to system 2 to check the existed folders, we'll receive a name and id(but it would be id for system 2 not for the first one) and parent id(the same way).

Comment: @Skazalasobaka: When you send `(parent_id, name)` to system 2, will you get the new id of system 2 in return? Or do you really have to read all current folders in system 2 each time?

Comment: You're right. We could achieve a response.json and receive an ID of just created folder

Comment: @Skazalasobaka: Have added some pseudo code. Please check and let me know if you still need help, e.g. translating to python!

Comment: from the start system 2 has no ids, its empty, and we should start to creating folders

Comment: @Skazalasobaka: I know. My pseudo code is respecting this. Please check!

Comment: @Skazalasobaka Do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that, using two functions with:

```
def find_sys2_parent_folder(folder_name: str):
response = requests.request(
    "GET",
    url_f,
    headers=headers,
)
for i in response:
    if i["values"]["name"] == folder_name:
        return i["parent_id"]


def create_sys2_folders(folders: List):
for i in folders:
    if i["parent_id"] is not None:
        i["parent_id"] = find_sys2_parent_folder(i["name"])
    response = requests.request(
        "POST",
        url_f,
        headers=headers,
        json=i
    )
    pprint(response)
```